# Azure Mobile Apps - Node.js backend - Android Client Custom Authentication

Tags: android, node.js, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I am currently trying to implement custom authentication within an Android app built using Azure Mobile Apps as the back-end. I've followed numerous different bits of information and feel I am going circles and probably missing something simple at this stage. I will list everything I have done in as much detail as possible.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

Authentcation using login credentials stored within a table of the Database.

**What have I got so far?**

So far I've got a custom api validating user/password credentials and then returning a JWT token using *'azure-mobile-apps/src/auth'*

[Result from my login API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Rx9.png)

[To get this api working I used this Github repo as a reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/samples/custom-authentication/api/login.js)

I know that this token works because when I try to access one of my apis marked with authenticated access only I receive the following message: *You must be logged in to use this application* but when I attach the token as a header with *"x-zumo-auth"* I can access the api without any problem.

**Where am I stuck?**

I'm stuck at the point where I recieve my token within the Android client and try to authenticate the MobileServiceClient using it. I've tried a few different methods but can't seem to figure out the correct one, what I currently have is this:

```
User user = new Gson().fromJson(result.getAsJsonObject().get("user"), User.class);
Log.d(TAG, "User: " + user.toString());
Log.d(TAG, result.getAsJsonObject().get("token").toString());
MobileServiceUser mobileServiceUser = new 
MobileServiceUser(user.getUsername());
mobileServiceUser.setAuthenticationToken(
                          result.getAsJsonObject().get("token").toString());
mClient.setCurrentUser(mobileServiceUser);
```

User is just a basic object which holds the other information returned from the login api.

After performing the above bit of code I get the following stacktrace when I try to access one of the custom apis which require authentication. There is no message within the {} so I really just don't know where to go from here. Perhaps someone has done this before and knows what I'm missing?

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {}
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:500)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:479)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:76)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at ie.iskill.iskillmanagementmobile.azure.AzureServiceAdapter$3$1$1.run(AzureServiceAdapter.java:153)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err: Caused by: com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {}
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:128)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$15.handleRequest(MobileServiceClient.java:1610)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection.start(MobileServiceConnection.java:113)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:78)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:35)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   09-29 09:12:43.151 17172-17370/{package} W/System.err:     ... 1 more

**What have I tried?**

So many different variations of things it wouldn't be feasible to list them all here, I have never posted here before because I usually prefer just bashing my head against things to figure them out, but this time I am truly stumped. 
I've browsed a few different questions, and found a 'zumo book' which contains a chapter on custom authentication by AdrianHall (I can't link more than two links with my reputation.) mentioned in a few questions but couldn't find an answer to my question in it.

If I have left anything out that would be of use to know please let me know in a reply so I can add it as quick as possible.

**Android SDK Used:** *compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0@aar'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me preface this answer by starting with: I am very silly!

Everything was working as expected on the back-end, hence why the token worked on Postman for the x-zumo-auth header.

I however used the following bit of code to extract my token:

```
result.getAsJsonObject().get("token").toString()
```

When I should have had it as follows:

```
result.getAsJsonObject().get("token").getAsString()
```

The reason for this was the .toString() method was leaving quotes on my token, so instead of being eySKANDadnzl65... it was reading as "eySDKANDadnzl65..." with the quotes.

This was causing the client to return the no-message Exception. I only noticed it by reading the logs numerous times and spotting that when I output the token everytime it had the "'s attached to it.

I will leave this here just in-case someone else happens to make this mistake like I did.